# Issue with displaying the output from a service Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsarray

Below is Array which i get it from service.

```
{
    ClassDays = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday";
    empName = Abhinav;
    Experience = "4 Years";
    Attendance = Daily;
    Subject = Physics;
    ClassTimings =     (
                       {
                           GMT = "PLUS05:30";
                           Time = "12:50:00";
                           TimeZone = "Asia/Hyderabad";
                       },
                       {
                           GMT = "PLUS05:30";
                           Time = "13:00:00";
                           TimeZone = "Asia/Hyderabad";
                       },
                       {
                           GMT = "PLUS05:30";
                           Time = "13:10:00";
                           TimeZone = "Asia/Hyderabad";
                       },
                       {
                           GMT = "PLUS05:30";
                           Time = "13:20:00";
                           TimeZone = "Asia/Hyderabad";
                       }
                       );
    JoinedDate = "2017-003-06";
    Education = M.Tech;
    empId = 535;
}
```

My Problem is from the above Array output am able to show the values of empName,Experience,Attendance,Subject and Education, but not able to show the ClassTimings GMT,Time,TimeZone. How can i Show the ClassTimings from below Array. Below is the code i have tried. Please help me to find the issue. TIA

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

       //Some code
    }

    NSArray *keys = [empDict allKeys];

    for(int i=0 ; i<[keys count]; i++ )
    {

        NSString *value=[medicationDict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
        if ([value isEqual: [NSNull null]]) {

            [empDict setValue:@"--" forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];

        }

    }

    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"EmployeeName";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"empName"];
    }

    if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Experience";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"Experience"];
    }

    if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Attendance";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"Attendance"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==3)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Subject";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"Subject"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==4)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Education";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"Education"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==5)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"ClassTimings";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"GMT",
                                   @"Time",@"TimeZone"];
    }
}
```

Comment: `ClassTimings` is array of dictionary so you need to add tableView in your cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple You can get array from your Json and pass in tableview index path  row Because ClassTimings is making array from your JsonDictionary

If only show Only single row

```
 if(index path.row ==5)
{
 NSString *stgmt = [empDict objectForKey:@"GMT"];;

 NSString *strtime = [empDict  objectForKey:@"Time"];; 

 NSString *strtimeZone = [empDict objectForKey:@"TimeZone"];
}
```

// if You want to make array and show each tableview row than its logic

```
  yourArray = [jsonDict  objectForKey:@"ClassTimings"];
 NSString *stgmt = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"GMT"];;

 NSString *strtime = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Time"];; 

 NSString *strtimeZone = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"TimeZone"];;
```

Comment: are you seen this `if(indexPath.row==5)` , it is the static Index

Comment: Then how can i assign GMT,Time and TimeZone to label

Comment: stgmt, strtime, strtimeZone You will get value in this pass this value in label